# When I Place A PDF, It Does Not Show The Correct Artboard Size (Doesn't account for the empty white artboard)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, artboard

The white box is showing what the art board size is when I open the PDF in illustrator (To edit). Yet when I go to place the PDF in a new document, the size changes. It is not saving he white/blank space on the art board, and just saving it to the art that's in the file. It's an illustrator setting, because when I open it in acrobat, it shows the white space included.

My last step in pre flight is throwing it in a new doc to make sure the sizing is correct, and there's no hidden layers that show up for print.

The obvious solution is to just add a white box in my art file, but I would like to know a fix that doesn't include that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the correct option when placing the PDF:

[image]

- **Bounding Box**
   Imports based upon the bounding area of the artwork in the placed file (sounds like what you're using)
- **Art**
   Imports based upon the artwork edges in the placed file (could also be what you're using)
- **Crop**
   Imports based upon crop marks within the placed file if they exist, otherwise uses Media
- **Trim**
   Imports based upon trim marks within the placed file if they exist, otherwise uses Media
- **Bleed**
   Imports based upon the defined bleed size of the placed artwork, if defined, otherwise uses Media
- **Media**
   Imports based upon the artboard (or page) size of the placed file.

Comment: Is there a way to set it to default? I usually just drag and drop from the folders.

Comment: @Christian To the best of my knowledge it stays on whatever you set it to. So use File > Place for one file and set it accordingly, then you should be able to drag/drop with the same results.